# How to setup vagrant with ubuntu as development server on windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, flask, vagrant

I installed vagrant on my windows 10 with ubuntu. I want to make ubuntu as my development environment.

In my Vagrantfile I uncomment forwarded_port and edit as follows:

*config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"*

Here, I want to access in my browser under the windows if I run pyhon on ubuntu.

In, ubuntu I created a simple "hello world" python script using flask framework. I called it main.py. When i run the script with command '**python main.py**', it says:

"Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/"...

So, back in my windows, I tried to access the link to my browser. Unfortunately, the "hello world" did not show up.

Is there anything I need to do in the setup? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the VM, 127.0.0.1 is local, and the world outside the VM isn't. Change your `run()` to include `host='0.0.0.0'`, or switch to using the `flask` command, and pass `--host=0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thank you Dave. I follow your advice and its working...

I added the host and port:

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0',port=5000)